# Showing that the Limit of a Complex Integral Equals 0

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb{C}$ and $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $\lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{|z| = r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2} dz = 0$.

My attempt so far:

Since $f$ is bounded, we know that $\exists M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \le M$, $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. Also, because $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$, it must be true that $\bigg|\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}dt \ \bigg| \leq \int_{|z|=r} \bigg|\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}| dz$.

My hint is to estimate $\int_{|z|=r} \bigg|\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}| dz$ and show that it goes to $0$. However, I am not seeing why this expression involving absolute value comes into play and I am not sure where to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re on the right track. Notice that by the triangle inequality, $$|z-a|\geq|z|-|a|$$ and as long as $|z|=r$ is sufficiently large, this implies $$|z-a|\geq r-r/2=r/2.$$ Therefore $$\int_{|z|=r}|\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}||dz|\leq\int_{|z|=r}\frac{M}{(r/2)^2}|dz|=2\pi r\frac M{(r/2)^2}=O(r^{-1})\to0.$$

Clarification: Originally $dz$ is a complex measure, but after pulling the absolute value inside the integral it is just the arclength measure along the circle (hence $|dz|$). For comparison, $\int_{|z|=r}dz=0$ while $\int_{|z|=r}|dz|=2\pi r$.

Comment: after Therefore: The middle integral is $0.$ You don't mean what you wrote there.

Comment: @zhw. True, although then the first inequality would be false. Clarification added.